# How to insert bullet points like circle shape in HTML?

Tags: html

This my guess but its not correct what is your wish

```html
<ul style="list-type:circle">
  <li>Regno</li>
  <li>class</li>
  <li>subject</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear

Comment: Don't guess. Read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You are close, it's `list-style-type` CSS tag, not `list-type`.

```
<ul style="list-style-type:disc">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

It's also the default style behavior, so you can just use `<ul>` with no `style` attribute.

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul style="list-style-type:circle">
  <li>Item1</li>
  <li>Item2</li>
  <li>Item3</li>
  </ul>
<br>
```

Try something like this. There are multiple list-style-types you can use, which include "disc", "circle", "square", and "none".

Answer (score 0):

You need to use    list-style-type:circle or    list-style-type:disc whichever you prefer.

Also you should try to avoid inline css as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Its some what the basics things you have to know, I will help you.
You can use any of the below code for this sitution.

```
<ul style="list-style-type:circle">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

OR

```
<ul style="list-style-type:disc">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

You can know more about list type styling http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp

I think it may help you.